# jsf outputlabel can't find variable

Tags: jsf, glassfish, javabeans

I'm new in JSF, and after 1h searching for solution, I decidet to ask here for solution.

So after I add two things in my code, one is String msg; and athor public check() method to my Users.class, I did get "/index.xhtml @12,50 value="#{users.msg}": The class 'users.Users' does not have the property 'msg'." error.

When i removing line:

```
<h:outputLabel id="outlbl" value="#{users.msg}"/><br/>
```

and replace action to action="index" from Submit button, it works fine.

Here is it my simple Users.java code:

```
package users;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Users {

private String name;
private String msg;

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void check(){
    if(name.equals("java")) {
        msg = "Valid user!";
    } else {
        msg = "Invalid User!";
    }
}
}
```

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h:form>
            <h:outputLabel id="outlbl" value="#{users.msg}"/><br/>
            <h:outputText id="outtxt" value="#{users.name}"/><br/>
            <h:inputText id="intxt" value="#{users.name}"/><br/>
            <h:commandButton id="btn" value="Submit" action="#{users.check()}"/>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Sorry if it's stupid question, but I need to solve it before I will move forward.

Answer (score 0):

The web.xml is incomplete, you need to add the faces servlet. Add this lines of code

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and modify

```
<welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
```

with

```
<welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
```

**Edit1**
It should work now. As an advice, @ManagedBean will become deprecated, so use @Named instead. Make the following modifications:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
```

with the imports:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
```

Comment: Thanks for that fast answer, but still same error: '/index.xhtml @12,62 value="#{users.msg}": The class 'users.Users' does not have the property 'msg'.". Any more ideas?

Comment: Alex, since JSF 2.2 / Servlet 3.0, the `FacesServlet` is auto-registered on `*.jsf`, `*.faces` and `/faces/*`. See also [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html). Even then, if `FacesServlet` was not properly mapped, the Facelets file with all JSF tags would be served as plain text and all EL expressions would never be evaluated and thus impossibly cause this kind of exception. OP however got an exception during evaluating EL, so this means that Facelets file is properly parsed which in turn means that `FacesServlet` is successfully invoked.

Comment: I've edited my answer. If it still fails to work, please tell me on what server you are running your app.

Comment: Alex, OP tagged `[glassfish]` and the presence of JSF 2.2 specific XML namespace in code suggests Glassfish version 4.0.

Comment: BalusC yes, you are right. Now i see them. His code should work fine.

Comment: Alex, sorry but same error. Yes, i'm using glassfish server, and JSF 2.0 version. Actually i have warning about deprecated in bouth ManagedBean and SessionScope. After replacing ManageBean to Named, only SessionScope has warning. But still same error.

Comment: You need to use the import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

Comment: Alex, BalusC, I'm ready to smash my keyboard :) Still error. can I export my code and send it to you guys?

Comment: Try cleaning your project and build it again. I don't see anything wrong with your code.